# Устанавливаю wav2png

Tags: centos

Нужно установить [wav2png](https://github.com/beschulz/wav2png). Сделал всё что нужно. Но вот такая проблема.

```
[root@ua0014901 ~]# makemake: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот такое написано (для Centos):

```
yum install libsndfile-devel boost-devel libpng-devel gcc-c++cd wav2png/dependencies/includewget http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/pngpp/png++-0.2.5.tar.gztar zxvf png++-0.2.5.tar.gz && rm png++-0.2.5.tar.gzmv png++-0.2.5 png++cd ../../build
```

ваша ошибка говорит что вы не сделали последнего действия, или что-то пропустили.

Comment: Мне уже сделали.